# Scala js Jquery offset result how to use?

Tags: scala, scala.js

I'm using this library https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js-jquery
And need to get and use result of offset method of jQuery. But this method returns js.native and I don't know how to get value from Javascript object { top=1227.5, left=416.5}. How this can be achieved?

Comment: Please provide what you have already tried. Some code etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it doesn't *return* `js.native` -- `js.native` just means "this is implemented in JavaScript". What's it's returning is effectively a js.Dynamic. (The fact that it's marked as js.Any is kind of unfortunate.) You could cast it to js.Dynamic, use that to fetch top and left, and cast *those* to Double.

Or (better) you could define a facade, along these lines:

```
@ScalaJSDefined
trait JQueryPosition extends js.Object {
  val left:Double
  val top:Double
}
```

and cast the returned value from `offset` to that.

Or you could switch to using [jquery-facade](https://github.com/jducoeur/jquery-facade), which does it this way in the first place...